# Getting Exception while passing url dynamically in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uri

I have a Xamarin app, it works well when the url's are static. But as soon as I save the selected language in Preferences and fetch the language selection to pass it as a querystring in Uri, I get the following exception:

[image]

Here is the exception:
Message (System.ArgumentException)  "Value is an invalid value for Uri\nParameter name: value"  string

Here is the Stack Trace:
StackTrace  "  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)\n  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)\n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop…"   string

Here is the working code:

[image]

Here is the code that throws error, when at the runtime there is a change in the url

[image]

The url's are saved as

public static string _getCategories =  controllerFeeds + "GetCategories?IsMobile=true&refresh=1";

Any help is much appreciated!!

I have tried with every possible url configuration, but the exception is same. It only comes when I am dynamically adding a new querystring through Preferences.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images.  And what is the **actual value** of `categoryUrl` that causes the exception?

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your suggestion. After spending many hours on it, I reinstalled Visual Studio and Android sdk. Now, its working fine with no such error. 

I really don't know what caused this error and will try troubleshoot it for future help.  

Thanks